# Не могу понять, почему не записываются данные

Tags: java, scanner

Почему не записываются данные, которые я ввожу в `pointerFiller` через `Scanner` ни в `points[0] = new Point(x, y);`, ни в `points[i] = new Point(x, y);` , который в цикле.

```
public class Point {
    private int lineCount;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void pointsCreator() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        lineCount = scanner.nextInt();

        Point[] points = new Point[lineCount];

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("enter points for first line: ");
        pointerFiller(scanner);

        points[0] = new Point(x, y);

        for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++){
            System.out.println("----------------------");
            System.out.println("enter points for next line:");
            pointerFiller(scanner);

            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        }

        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
    }

    public static Point pointerFiller(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.print("     - enter x: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("     - enter y: ");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Points for line {x = " + x + ", y = " + y + '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У тебя в методе `pointerFiller` создаются **локальные** переменные `x,y`. После этого создается точка, которую ты возвращаешь, но ты её игнорируешь.
И вообще почему `pointsCreator` не статический?
Именно эту проблему можно решить так:

```
public void pointsCreator() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    lineCount = scanner.nextInt();

    Point[] points = new Point[lineCount];

    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("enter points for first line: ");
    points[0] = pointerFiller(scanner);

    for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++) {
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("enter points for next line:");
        points[i] = pointerFiller(scanner);
    }

    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
}
```

Comment: Ага! Сработало! СПАСИБО!